# I cant start this sqlite select code

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This sourch code for my app:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Note where Username = '"+acc+"'", null);

        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Note ", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Note_DTO note = new Note_DTO();
                note.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                note.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                note.setUser(cursor.getString(2));
                note.setContent(cursor.getString(3));
                NoteList.add(note);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
```

This function return nothing , but in debug mode , every single item was set .
Should it return a list of what i selected , i don't understand why and how it's not . Thanks for your help .

Comment: Be sure to check the spelling/lowercase/uppercase in your query. Run in debug mode to see what the query is, what value `acc` has etc. Is your table called 'Username' or 'username'? Check the small stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
   String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Note where Username " + " LIKE '%" + acc + "%'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        database.close();
        if(count==0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


                do {

                   Note_DTO note = new Note_DTO();
                note.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                note.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                note.setUser(cursor.getString(2));
                note.setContent(cursor.getString(3));
                NoteList.add(note);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use `getReadableDatabase()` for query purposes as follows.**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

**Please Read `SQLiteOpenHelper` documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29) for `getReadableDatabase()`**

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
>   by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>   requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>   read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>   future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>   read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>   will be returned in the future.

**Read `SQLiteOpenHelper` documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()) for `getWritableDatabase()`**

> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
>   writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened
>   and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
>   and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called.
>
> Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this
>   method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to
>   call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad
>   permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future
>   attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.

According to the `getWritableDatabase()` documentation, it clearly mentions that it will cache the database. So it's possible to retrieve data from a cached copy of your database. As same as make sure you've closed the database connection after your transaction.

**Finally your code would be like this**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Note where Username = '"+acc+"'", null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Note_DTO note = new Note_DTO();
        note.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        note.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
        note.setUser(cursor.getString(2));
        note.setContent(cursor.getString(3));
        NoteList.add(note);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

}
```